# Return Multiple exit status to nagios

Tags: shell-script, nagios

I'm trying to write a shell script for nagios plugin. I have a list of failed nodes where I have to trigger a CRITICAL alert to the nagios.

**Input:**

```
#cat file
 OFFLINE
 OFFLINE
 OFFLINE
 OFFLINE
```

All I want is to send exit status(i.e 2) for all the OFFLINE nodes. And, here is my code below so far.

**CODE**

```
while read -r output;
do
  STATE=$(echo $output)

  if [ $STATE == "OFFLINE" ]; then
        echo "CRITICAL: STATE is $STATE" 
        exit 2
  else
        echo  "OK " > /dev/null
  fi
done< <( cat file )
```

But the problem is the loop runs for one time and exits with 2 and alert goes for one node and for the remaining node I need to send the alert. Is there any way to write this script?

Comment: don't exit?  but last I knew, Nagios only accepted one return code per system/check.

Comment: If you issue an `exit` command, how do you expect your script to continue running ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller is there any other way I can send alert to all offline node?

Comment: @MelBurslan Yeah i know but nagios expects only the exit code(0,1,2,3). if you know any other way to send the status code to nagios. It would be helpful for me.

Comment: Nagios triggers alerts for hosts on which a host or service check has failed. Last I knew, you couldn't tell Nagios "if a service check on host1 fails, alert for hosts 2, 3, and 4" You might be able to work around it with a service dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Nagios and it s operation but if it takes only one exit code at a time, you will need to modify your script a little and run it multiple times.

```
output=$(head -1 file)  # read first line
sed -i -e '1,1d' file   # delete the first line

  STATE=$(echo $output)

  if [ $STATE == "OFFLINE" ]; then
        echo "CRITICAL: STATE is $STATE" 
        exit 2
  else
        echo  "OK " > /dev/null
  fi
```

If you can run this segment multiple times, you will receive multiple exit codes.

Comment: I used your idea to run the script multiple times using for loop in calling the above script. and It worked fine. Used two scripts and got the job done.